# Part of Facebook object is displaying as undefined, but it isn't undefined

Tags: javascript, object, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm working with results from the Facebook Javascript SDK, and the "attachments" part of the object is giving me trouble. When looking at the object it's all good, but when I try to display it on my website, it says these properties are undefined. Am I parsing incorrectly?

Here's the object:

```
{
"id":"xxx_xxx",
"from":{
    "id":"xxxx",
    "name":"User Name"
},
"to":{
    "data":[{
        "name":"Group Name",
        "id":"xxxx"
    }]
},
"picture":"url of image",
"link":"url",
"object_id":"Object ID",
"type":"photo",
"created_time":"2014-10-15T21:09:19+0000",
"updated_time":"2014-10-15T21:09:19+0000",
"attachments":{
    "data":[{
        "media":{
            "image":{
                "height":551,
                "src":"Image Source",
                "width":720
            }
        },
        "target":{
            "id":"742450405803347",
            "url":"target URL"
        },
        "type":"photo",
        "url":"URL"
    }]
}
```

And here's the code to display the "attachments" part on the website (I know it's messy, please ignore that):

```
post_div_html += '<p>------------------</p>\
                <p><b>Media-Image-Source</b>: ' + feed.attachments.data[0] + '</p>\
                <p><b>Target URL</b>: ' + feed.attachments.data[1] + '</p>\
                <p><b>Type</b>: ' + feed.attachments.data[2] + '</p>\
                <p><b>URL</b>: ' + feed.attachments.data[3] + '</p></div>';
```

Now, just to be clear, what you see there results in 'undefined' being displayed as the value on my website. Everything else I have tried has resulted in an error saying that 'feed.attachments.data.whatever is undefined'.

Anyone have any ideas on how I need to be displaying this stuff?

Comment: For starters, whilst `feed.attachments.data` is indeed an array, it only has one element so you can't use an index higher than 0. Anything else (such as 1, 2 and 3 as you have in your code) is most certainly *undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is...

```
var att = feed.attachments.data[0],
    mediaImageSrc = att.media.image.src,
    targetUrl = att.target.url,
    type = att.type,
    url = att.url;
```

I hope that makes sense.

Here's a working example...

```js
var feed = {
  "id": "xxx_xxx",
  "from": {
    "id": "xxxx",
    "name": "User Name"
  },
  "to": {
    "data": [{
      "name": "Group Name",
      "id": "xxxx"
    }]
  },
  "picture": "url of image",
  "link": "url",
  "object_id": "Object ID",
  "type": "photo",
  "created_time": "2014-10-15T21:09:19+0000",
  "updated_time": "2014-10-15T21:09:19+0000",
  "attachments": {
    "data": [{
      "media": {
        "image": {
          "height": 551,
          "src": "Image Source",
          "width": 720
        }
      },
      "target": {
        "id": "742450405803347",
        "url": "target URL"
      },
      "type": "photo",
      "url": "URL"
    }]
  }
};

var att = feed.attachments.data[0],
  mediaImageSrc = att.media.image.src,
  targetUrl = att.target.url,
  type = att.type,
  url = att.url;

post_div_html = '<p>------------------</p>\
                <p><b>Media-Image-Source</b>: ' + mediaImageSrc + '</p>\
                <p><b>Target URL</b>: ' + targetUrl + '</p>\
                <p><b>Type</b>: ' + type + '</p>\
                <p><b>URL</b>: ' + url + '</p></div>';
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = post_div_html;
```

```html
<output id="out"></output>
```